# Irrep of stress energy tensor

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory

We have 4-tensor of second rank. For example energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, which is symmetric and traceless. Then

$T_{\mu\nu}=x_{\mu}x_{\nu}+x_{\nu}x_{\mu}$

where $x_{\mu}$ is 4-vector. Every 4- vector transform under Lorentz transform as $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.
If we act on $T_{\mu\nu}$, by representation( with homomorphism) then we have

$$D(T_{\mu\nu})=(D(x_{\mu})\otimes D(x_{\nu}))\oplus (D(x_{\nu})\otimes D(x_{\mu}))$$,or

$T_{\mu\nu}$ transform as 
$$(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\oplus(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})=(1\oplus0)\oplus(1\oplus0)=1\oplus1\oplus0 \oplus0$$

But we have trace of two components $0$. On wikipedia write that traceless symmetric tensors transform on representation $(1,1)=2\oplus0$.

Where is error?

Comment: Hint: Think carefully about when to use $\oplus$ vs. $\otimes$.